# Getting the 3rd DIV inside a DIV in DOM

Tags: php, dom

I have a crawler which crawls a site for a specific value, this value is not directly located inside of a class div but of course has a parent div with is specified by a class.
this value is located in the 3rd div of the parent div (if you look below you will see what i mean).

**code**

```
if($page->find('div.mbcContainer div div span')){       
   foreach($page->find('div.mbcContainer div div span') as $p){ 
      if(trim($p->plaintext)){                      
         $tp = $p->plaintext;
      }
   }
}
```

**html page**

```
<div class="mbcContainer">
   <div>
      <div class="ie1"></div>
      <div class="ie2"></div>
      <div>
         <span>get this value</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the span with the value "get this value"
is there any way to do this.

Comment: You could tag the span with a class then find the class. `$page->find('.thespanclass') as $p`

Comment: @Norse it's not my website im crawling, I have no control over the span class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
This does the trick:

```
echo $page->find('div.mbcContainer div', 0)->children(2);
```

Or if you want to iterate through:

```
foreach ($page->find('div.mbcContainer div') as $p) {
    echo $p->children(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.mbcContainer div div:nth-child(3) span
```